# What is the point of the "yes" command?

Tags: command, yes

There is a `yes` command in unix/linux which basically infinitely prints `y` to the `stdout`. What is the point of it, and how is it useful?

Comment: A few extra possibilities [here](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/tagged/154/yes).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the point of the \`yes\` command?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102484/what-is-the-point-of-the-yes-command)... (Flagging this as duplicate because the other newer question is better asked and better answered).

Comment: Relating: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/257297/117549

Comment: https://matthias-endler.de/2017/yes/

Answer (score 53, accepted):

> yes can be used to send an affirmative (or negative; e.g. yes n)
>   response to any command that would otherwise request one, thereby
>   causing the command to run non-interactively.
>
> The yes command in conjunction with the head command can be used to
>   generate large volume files for means of testing.
>
> It can also be used to test how well a system handles high loads, as
>   using yes results in 100% processor usage, for systems with a single
>   processor (for a multiprocessor system, a process must be run for each
>   processor). This, for example, can be useful for investigating whether
>   a system's cooling system will be effective when the processor is
>   running at 100%.
>
> In 2006, the yes command received publicity for being a means to test
>   whether or not a user's MacBook is affected by the Intermittent
>   Shutdown Syndrome. By running the yes command twice via Terminal under
>   Mac OS X, users were able to max out their computer's CPU, and thus
>   see if the failure was heat related

via wikipedia: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes_(Unix)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes_%28Unix%29)

Comment: For extra damage, try `yes \`yes yes\``

Comment: @sendmoreinfo [Evil](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/100647/what-does-yes-yes-yes-do)

Comment: ohh, thats a nice stress test. just tried it, then ran to my colleague asking for a new vm xD

Answer (score 24):

This might be a controversial opinion, but in my view **it is an ugly fix for bad user interface in command-line tools**.

Some command-line tools ask questions to the user with a prompt and do not have an option to run non-interactively; imagine for instance something such as

```
$ frobnicate *
frobnicate file a.txt? (y/n) y
frobnicate file b.txt? (y/n) y
...
```

Since the answer to the question is taken from standard input, a quick fix to this problem is having an application that outputs the string `y\n` continuously, which is exactly what `yes` does. Unix [pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29) can be used to send this output as an input to a given command.

```
$ yes | frobnicate
```

One of the issues with this approach is that `yes` has no possibility to check the question it is answering to:

```
frobnicate file a.txt? (y/n) y
frobnicate file b.txt? (y/n) y
format device /dev/sda1? (y/n) y
frobnicate file c.txt? (y/n) y
```

A better solution, when it is available, is a specific option to run non-interactively, such as `rm -f` or `apt-get -y`. This allows coding more sensible behavior in the application.

Comment: I read all the other answers.  I agree with yours completely w.r.t. ugly fix...though it *does* have a valid use for testing computer's response to high cpu loads.

Comment: Of course, you could use the proprietary software "Microsoft Windows" to test computer response to high cpu loads, but "yes" is open source.

Comment: It's one of the most beautiful ugly fixes though

Answer (score 6):

I like to use `yes` when I am unzipping multiple .zip files that all contain the same file with the same name and I am asked what to do in each case (ex. a licence agreement).

```
yes | for z in *.zip; do unzip "$z"; done
```

Comment: Arguably, the -u or -n options to unzip would accomplish much the same thing, but I can definitely see and agree how a generic and easily-memorable solution that works across a wide number of tasks beats trying to memorize a specific solution just for unzip, or worse, looking it up in the man page every darn time.

Answer (score 4):

Just came across another use for it: liked to wipe out a hard disk with a different pattern than just zeroes (like: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdd bs=1M`) and used '**yes**' for it:

`yes UUUUUUUUUUUUU > /dev/sdd`

Comment: Beware though that it does fill up the disk with `U`s but with `UUUUUUUUUUUUU\n`s. To fill up with `U`s, you'd need `yes '' | tr '\n' U > /dev/sdd` or `tr '\0' U < /dev/zero > /dev/sdd`

Answer (score 2):

A coworker used this in a novel way to input a password

```
yes password | passwd
```

Comment: `passwd` will ask for the old password first, if the user is not _root_ or a _superuser_ and will not continue unless the correct password is entered. So either the user is _root_ or `password` is the old password as well and nothing is changed.

Comment: @MichaelKonietzka indeed. But with the conditions you mentioned it's a useful use case still.

Comment: Except this would persist in history in plaintext. Crazeyyy.

Comment: @Gleno in bash, you can precede it with a space to prevent it from being recorded (as in http://stackoverflow.com/q/640403/118153)

Comment: Also, this leaks the password to all local users in the process list (`ps` or `top` at the right moment).