# What does yes $(yes yes) do?

Tags: command

Wondering what use the `yes` command might be, I stumbled upon [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47344/the-yes-command#comment106172_47346), and tried to execute

```
yes $(yes yes)
```

From what I understand, this should simply print out an infinite sequence of `yes`, but instead it outputs nothing and crashes my graphical terminal after a few seconds. (If I execute it on tty1, I see the login prompt after some time.)

What is happening here?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but it might be that the first invocation is trying to print infinity infinite times. (or the argument may simply be too long.)

Comment: @strugee The argument list is never populated, because `yes` never returns.

Comment: @strugee You can get "infinity infinite times" using `xargs`: `yes yes | xargs -P 0 yes` (or without `-P 0` for single-process infinity)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It should already be enough to run

```
 echo $(yes yes)
```

The `$(...)` runs the inner command until it is finished and captures all its output. - Now as `yes` runs a long time and generates a lot of output, bash will eventually run out of memory and crash.

Answer (score 9):

To see the message for the error which closes your shell, you need to run a sub-shell.

```
$ sh
$ kill -9 $$
Killed
$

$ sh
$ yes $(yes yes)
sh: xrealloc: cannot allocate 18446744071562067968 bytes
$
```

Comment: 16 million gigabytes, eh? Gordon Moore is lurking in a corner going, "Well... I mean, not quite _yet_..."