# What is the point of the `yes` command?

Tags: utilities

This question concerns the `yes` command found in UNIX and Linux machines: Basically, what is the point (if any) and history of this tool? Are there practical applications for it? Can an example be shown where it is useful in a script or chained (via pipe or redirect) with another tool?

The manpage is below:

```
YES(1)                    BSD General Commands Manual                   YES(1)

NAME
     yes -- be repetitively affirmative

SYNOPSIS
     yes [expletive]

DESCRIPTION
     yes outputs expletive, or, by default, ``y'', forever.

HISTORY
     The yes command appeared in 4.0BSD.

4th Berkeley Distribution        June 6, 1993        4th Berkeley Distribution
```

Sample output:

```
$ yes why
why
why
why
why
^Cwhy
```

Comment: Stumbled upon this when I thought I had received a "yes" dialogue but really I had be kicked out the prompt. Surprise! `yes yes yes yes yes yes yes` ...

Answer (score 117, accepted):

It's usually used as a quick and dirty way to provide answers to an interactive script:

```
yes | rm -r large_directory
```

will not prompt you about any file being removed. Of course in the case of `rm`, you can always supply `-f` to make it steamroll the directory removal, but not all tools are so forgiving.

**Update**

A more relevant example of this that I recently came across is when you are `fsck`ing a filesystem and you don't want to bother answering `y` when prompted before fixing each error:

```
yes | fsck /dev/foo
```

Comment: Does that mean that the `yes` output would cease once the `rm` is completed?

Comment: @JarydMalbin, yes, because that's the default behavior of SIGPIPE.

Comment: @JarydMalbin Yes it does. When `rm` stops reading from the pipe (read: completes), `yes` gets a SIGPIPE as in cjm's comment

Comment: According to the manual, `fsck -y /dev/foo` should do the same on some file systems. Most I'd say: the manual notes exceptions for minix and cramfs.

Answer (score 29):

Beside the main point mentioned in the [previous answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/102487/22565) the `yes` command can also be used to test high loads of CPU on a system. `yes` creates a process which acts as a dummy CPU loader and results in 100% processor usage. [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes_(Unix)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes_%28Unix%29)

Answer (score 12):

When updating ports on a FreeBSD workstation, using portmaster + yes becomes very handy:

```
yes | portmaster -da
```

That way you can let the machine update while you lunch and all the questions fill default to 'y,yes'

When [rebuilding the world](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/makeworld.html) for 'make delete-old' and 'make delete-old-libs'.

this is a big time saver:

```
yes | make delete-old
```

and

```
yes | make delete-old-libs
```

Basically helps you to avoid typing / confirm certain operations that ask for a 'y' or 'yes'