# Linux command that continuously outputs string of text

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, text

At some point I used a shell command that continuously sent a very short string of text to the standard output, but at this moment I can't recall it's name.

Its name was something very short, like 'abc', useful to quickly create a file filled with text. I remember I was surprised I had never seen it, so I guess it might not be a Linux built-in command. It actually might be a zsh shell command, but at the moment I do not have access to a zsh shell. I tried to find it in bash with "compgen -c" but either is not there or I can't recall the name

I know I can script it, but I am curious whether someone knows about it

Comment: do you mean the tee command ?  to redirect stdout to a file ?  or the yes command  to send only to stdout ?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257297/how-does-yes-write-to-file-so-quickly and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102484/what-is-the-point-of-the-yes-command/102487#102487

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's the command `yes(1)`

> yes - output a string repeatedly until killed