# Pass 'y' to plink command's interactive prompt

Tags: bash, ssh, putty

I'm trying to use `plink` to establish a connection to a remote server and remove an entry in SIP user directory list using the following command:

```
plink root@<server-ip> -pw pwd serctl ul rm bob
```

which then asks the following:

```
The server's host key is not cached. You have no guarantee
that the server is the computer you think it is.
The server's rsa2 key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 1024 5d:ae:ae:ad:46:71:30:6d:0c:0e:30:e1:cd:f7:6b:90
If you trust this host, enter "y" to add the key to
PuTTY's cache and carry on connecting.
If you want to carry on connecting just once, without
adding the key to the cache, enter "n".
If you do not trust this host, press Return to abandon the
connection.
Store key in cache? (y/n)
```

This comes up if the command is executed for the very first time. If I'm executing this command in a script, it invariably asks the same in the interactive prompt, but since no response is given, asks the same a few more times and prints :

```
Store key in cache? (y/n) Connection abandoned.
```

From the man page of [plink](https://linux.die.net/man/1/plink), I did get how to override the interactive prompt using `-batch` option, but I want to make sure that the response is positive i.e., a `y`. How can I make sure it is `y` explicitly? Is there a way I can add this to the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try the `yes` command if that is available on your distribution, see e.g.

- [What is the point of the `yes` command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102484/what-is-the-point-of-the-yes-command)
- [What is the point of the "yes" command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47344/what-is-the-point-of-the-yes-command)

for examples (and yes, these are two different questions despite the almost-same title).